# Create new mdb table using variable name

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm trying to create new tables in an existing mdb database, but assigning the new table names using a variable which has its value set from input entered in to a form. It works fine if I specify a name for the new table but fails when a variables value is used.

I have seen a few glimpses of posts that mention using dynamic sql but being completely unfamiliar with sql I haven't been able to grasp the advice. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%
table1 = Session("tableName")

set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & server.MapPath ("database.mdb")

Dim strSQL

'this works with explict naming and creates a table named table1
'strSQL = "CREATE TABLE table1 (field1 int, field2 char)"

'this does not work when trying to use a variable to set the tables name
 strSQL = "CREATE TABLE" & table1 & "(field1 int, field2 char)"

conn.Execute strSQL
conn.Close
%>
```

Comment: Need a space behind `TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an actual error message, it's going to be hard to give a more useful answer. However, there is one mistake that may or may not exist in your production code. You are missing the spaces around the table name so:

```
<%
table1 = Session("tableName")

set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & server.MapPath ("database.mdb")

Dim strSQL

'this does not work when trying to use a variable to set the tables name
 strSQL = "CREATE TABLE" & table1 & "(field1 int, field2 char)"

'this should be just fine - note the space after TABLE and before the quote. 
'   ditto for the space after the quote and before the open parens
 strSQL = "CREATE TABLE " & table1 & " (field1 int, field2 char)"

conn.Execute strSQL
conn.Close
%>
```

Comment: Thanks AnonJr and ZippyV – “spaces” are good.  I was expecting a thousand lines of unfamiliar sql code to fix my dilemma. I should remember what they say: “the smaller a problem is the harder it can be to solve” – just added the spaces and works as expected.